# R : Exclude empty records from LENGTH function

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I exclude empty or `NA` rows from `length` function?

I have a sample data.frame as follow:

```
Name     Index
Zed        1
Zed        0
Zed        0
Rye        NA
Ben        0
Ben        0
```

Desired output :

```
Name      Length
Zed         3
Rye         0
Ben         2
```

I have tried below :

```
data.table(dataset)[,c(LENGTH=length(INDEX)),by=list(NAME)]
```

The issue here is that the result for Rye is 1 instead of 0. How can I exclude `NA` from counting?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call that data frame x

```
aggregate(x,by=list(x$Name),function(x) length(na.omit(x)))
  Group.1 Name Index
1     Ben    2     2
2     Rye    1     0
3     Zed    3     3
```

na.omit would also work with your data table example.

Comment: Thanks JeremyS for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
> data.frame(Length = rowSums(table(dataset)))
##     Length
## Ben      2
## Rye      0
## Zed      3
```